# Changing run level causes freeze

Tags: xorg, services, init

I accidentally discovered that the Raspberry Pi 3 can run on 2.1A, so I constantly get the Lightning Bolt in the corner, indicating that I'm going to go over the limit it will let me.

So, to consume less "power" I decided I should not use the UI. I don't want to disable GUI on startup, so I `init 4`'d. That causes a freeze saying `Welcome to PIXEL` with `plymouth-start.service` in the bottom left corner. Then because it's worth a shot, I kept trying to kill Xorg. Didn't work either, but what I'm focusing on is `init 4` freezing with `plymouth`.

Comment: As Milliways points out, all SysV runlevels (except halt and single user) are the same on Debian/Raspbian.  You've been reading some documentation that was stale before the Pi was even invented.  Anyway, there's a sort of bug here in that ideally this shouldn't do anything (it may to keep some kind of backward compatibility, see `man init` and `man telinit`, obviously it isn't very useful).

Answer (score 2):

This has **NOTHING** to do with the (alleged) current rating of the power supply.

Not using the GUI will have negligible impact on the current drawn by the Pi.

Jessie **DOES NOT** use runlevels (except 0, 1, 7) all others are mapped to these.

The Voltage is too low and/or the cables are inadequate. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction to the above answer: *Jessie using `systemd` does not use runlevels*.

**If**, however you are a luddite or not a fan of (the hydra-like) `systemd` (like myself) you may have chosen to stick with the System V `init` which is a bit more *mature* (by a couple of decades?) like what I've done - however even then you may not see much difference when you use `sudo telinit #` where # is a different run-level number (or letter?).

On my system, I see the only difference for the run-levels 2 to 5 is that 2 does not run `lightdm` i.e. the system that starts `X` and presents a GUI login screen does not run in that normal level which is the sort of thing I think you are wanting - to configure the differences there are various tools and for the RPi I see that I have `sys-rc-conf(8)` which has both a CLI and a GUI - so read the `man` page for that or do an `apropos run level` and see what else might be relevant.

*Actually the reason I do not use `systemd` also has a connection to the fact that my RPi is running with an RPi specific UPS and I have written a daemon that communicates vital information to `init` ("um, the power has failed and the battery is running out - shutdown now please before it is completely exhausted!") via it's `/run/initctl` interface and the [`systemd` source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/initctl/initctl.c) for this, instead of doing anything with the messages merely logs: `Received UPS/power initctl request. This is not implemented in systemd. Upgrade your UPS daemon!`* - and I can't be arsed to do so when the `init` API is well defined and works perfectly well for me... 8-)